# Docker duplicates PGDATA folder when spawning container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have an issue using `postgres:9.5` official docker image.

I use Docker to share a development env between several developers. My setup is comprised of an image for the app code and another for the database. I orchestrate those through docker-compose. My issue is with the database image.

I'm using `postgres:9.5` official image as a base to create my db image. I do that with a daily running script that does something like:

```
# pull and run -d postgres:9.5 named "mydatabase" with custom $PGDATA
# run a container linked to "mydatabase" that populates the database
# commit and push to registry "mydatabase"
```

This creates an image we can simply reference in `docker-compose.yml`. Problem is that when the container is spawned, the whole `$PGDATA` directory is copied into container layer by AUFS driver.

Reading the doc tells me that AUFS driver does so because my container tried to write to the `$PGDATA` directory (Copy on Write strategy). But I don't see what could cause a write operation on this directory. It's quite annoying because my db is big and takes twice the disk space on developers computers (one for the mydatabase image and one for the spawned container).

Any ideas on why it happens and how should I solve this (I'm thinking about data-only containers but have to dig more into it)?

Many thanks

Precision 1: It is indeed the entire `$PGDATA` directory that gets copied into container layer (even files like PG_VERSION). Hence, it's not a SQL statement that cause the AUFS write.

Precision 2: to be able to persist and share data, I do not use volumes, my script (described above) sets a different `$PGDATA` value than `postgres:9.5` default. The data is consequently "persisted" inside the created image.

Precision 3: I do not override `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`, thus it's the values from `postgres:9.5` that gets executed.

Docker version 17.06.2-ce, build cec0b72

Answer (score 0):

The `$PGDATA` directory is used by postgres itself.

These are your steps:

#### 1. pull and run -d postgres:9.5 named "mydatabase" with custom $PGDATA

A container is created from the postgres image.

#### 2. run a container linked to "mydatabase" that populates the database

The above container receives populate requests and the postgres process write it data inside the `$PGDATA` directory.

#### 3. commit and push to registry "mydatabase"

The entire container, including the current `$PGDATA` folder, is saved as the image.

#### Conclusion

So you final image will have the size of the base postgres image + data submitted by your linked `mydatabase` container. When you start your new image, the postgres process will start and it will try to read and write the `$PGDATA` directory.

#### A real test

I've postgres on my laptop but I usually use it with a container, so it's last start was in 2016:

```
 docker ls -lah /usr/local/var/postgres
total 96
drwx------  25 alessandro  admin   850B 28 Ago  2016 .
drwxr-xr-x   8 alessandro  admin   272B 21 Set  2016 ..
-rw-------   1 alessandro  admin     4B 18 Mag  2016 PG_VERSION
drwx------   7 alessandro  admin   238B 20 Ago  2016 base
drwx------  54 alessandro  admin   1,8K 28 Ago  2016 global
drwx------   3 alessandro  admin   102B 18 Mag  2016 pg_clog
drwx------   2 alessandro  admin    68B 18 Mag  2016 pg_commit_ts
drwx------   2 alessandro  admin    68B 18 Mag  2016 pg_dynshmem
-rw-------   1 alessandro  admin   4,4K 18 Mag  2016 pg_hba.conf
-rw-------   1 alessandro  admin   1,6K 18 Mag  2016 pg_ident.conf
drwx------   4 alessandro  admin   136B 18 Mag  2016 pg_logical
drwx------   4 alessandro  admin   136B 18 Mag  2016 pg_multixact
drwx------   3 alessandro  admin   102B 28 Ago  2016 pg_notify
drwx------   2 alessandro  admin    68B 18 Mag  2016 pg_replslot
drwx------   2 alessandro  admin    68B 18 Mag  2016 pg_serial
drwx------   2 alessandro  admin    68B 18 Mag  2016 pg_snapshots
drwx------   7 alessandro  admin   238B 28 Ago  2016 pg_stat
drwx------   2 alessandro  admin    68B 28 Ago  2016 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------   3 alessandro  admin   102B 18 Mag  2016 pg_subtrans
drwx------   2 alessandro  admin    68B 18 Mag  2016 pg_tblspc
drwx------   2 alessandro  admin    68B 18 Mag  2016 pg_twophase
drwx------   5 alessandro  admin   170B  9 Lug  2016 pg_xlog
-rw-------   1 alessandro  admin    88B 18 Mag  2016 postgresql.auto.conf
-rw-------   1 alessandro  admin    21K 18 Mag  2016 postgresql.conf
-rw-------   1 alessandro  admin    79B 28 Ago  2016 postmaster.opts
```

Now I start it:

```
 docker postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

And there is the new state of my local folder, look at the edit time...

```
 docker ls -lah /usr/local/var/postgres
total 104
drwx------  26 alessandro  admin   884B  2 Ott 18:28 .
drwxr-xr-x   8 alessandro  admin   272B 21 Set  2016 ..
-rw-------   1 alessandro  admin     4B 18 Mag  2016 PG_VERSION
drwx------   7 alessandro  admin   238B 20 Ago  2016 base
drwx------  53 alessandro  admin   1,8K  2 Ott 18:28 global
drwx------   3 alessandro  admin   102B 18 Mag  2016 pg_clog
drwx------   2 alessandro  admin    68B 18 Mag  2016 pg_commit_ts
drwx------   2 alessandro  admin    68B 18 Mag  2016 pg_dynshmem
-rw-------   1 alessandro  admin   4,4K 18 Mag  2016 pg_hba.conf
-rw-------   1 alessandro  admin   1,6K 18 Mag  2016 pg_ident.conf
drwx------   4 alessandro  admin   136B 18 Mag  2016 pg_logical
drwx------   4 alessandro  admin   136B 18 Mag  2016 pg_multixact
drwx------   3 alessandro  admin   102B  2 Ott 18:28 pg_notify
drwx------   2 alessandro  admin    68B 18 Mag  2016 pg_replslot
drwx------   2 alessandro  admin    68B 18 Mag  2016 pg_serial
drwx------   2 alessandro  admin    68B 18 Mag  2016 pg_snapshots
drwx------   2 alessandro  admin    68B  2 Ott 18:28 pg_stat
drwx------   4 alessandro  admin   136B  2 Ott 18:28 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------   3 alessandro  admin   102B 18 Mag  2016 pg_subtrans
drwx------   2 alessandro  admin    68B 18 Mag  2016 pg_tblspc
drwx------   2 alessandro  admin    68B 18 Mag  2016 pg_twophase
drwx------   5 alessandro  admin   170B  9 Lug  2016 pg_xlog
-rw-------   1 alessandro  admin    88B 18 Mag  2016 postgresql.auto.conf
-rw-------   1 alessandro  admin    21K 18 Mag  2016 postgresql.conf
-rw-------   1 alessandro  admin    79B  2 Ott 18:28 postmaster.opts
-rw-------   1 alessandro  admin    81B  2 Ott 18:28 postmaster.pid
```

You say:

> It's quite annoying because my db is big and takes twice the disk space on developers computers (one for the mydatabase image and one for the spawned container).

But this is the default way Docker containers works.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. From doc (https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/#sharing-promotes-smaller-images): `When you start a container, a thin writable container layer is added on top of the other layers. Any changes the container makes to the filesystem are stored here. Any files the container does not change do not get copied to this writable layer...` Meaning my PGDATA directory is somehow written but it's not the default way container works

Comment: @htulipe if the answer solves your problem, please accept it. So future visitors can recognize it. Do you've tried it?

Comment: Hi @lifeisfoo, the answer does not solve my problem sorry. My main problem is that the whole PGDATA folder is copied over when container is spawned (multiplying disk space usage). From your answer I can see that your postgres instance also write the PGDATA folder (looking at the mtime of `.`) but I don't see why nor how to avoid it. Anyhow, I ended up using a Docker volume which solve that disk space issue.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/#the-copy-on-write-cow-strategy